# How do I 'get' a SSLContextRef from CFNetworks?

Tags: objective-c, ssl, cfnetwork

I am attempting to look at the SSLContext in a CFReadStream.  secureTransport has lots of useful methods for examining a SSLContextRef like SSLGetEnabledCiphers, but I don't have a good way to get a SSLContextRef from CFReadStream. Is there some sort of getter method for SSLContextRef in CFNetworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, take note, you can't.  What you can do is create a new SSL context, send the readstream to the context and encrypt the stream there.  What you can't is get the cipher settings from CFNetwork classes.  I suppose Apple wants them to remain private.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to retrieve the SSLContextRef using CFReadStreamCopyProperty. For example, see this code from the Apple [TLSTool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/sc1236/Introduction/Intro.html) sample:

```
context = (SSLContextRef) CFReadStreamCopyProperty((__bridge CFReadStreamRef) inputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLContext);
```

The kCFStreamPropertySSLContext is available as of OS X 10.9 and iOS 5.